# what does wsdl file refers?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to know about what is wsdl file and how it is useful in web services.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between XSD and WSDL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952015/what-is-the-difference-between-xsd-and-wsdl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Services Description Language (WSDL) is an language based on XML (XML like structure) for describing Web services and how to access them. 
You will create your web Service but other clients don't know what your web service does. Which is the end point, how to use the Webservice. I.e. where your web service is located and what methods (service it expose).

In simple terms, when you created your web Services, you know about that but the client who wants to use your service, they don't know anything about your service. So at this time WSDL come into picture.

its basic Syntax is

```
    <definitions>

<types>
  definition of types
</types>

<message>
  definition of a message....
</message>

<portType>
  definition of a port.......
</portType>

<binding>
  definition of a binding....
</binding>

</definitions>
```

W3schools is best to learn Basic of WSDL

[Click Here](http://www.w3schools.com/WSDL/wsdl_intro.asp)

Answer (score 2):

The Web Services Description Language (WSDL) is an XML-based grammar that defines the operations that a web service offers and the format of the request and response messages that the client sends to and receives from the operations

More details - [WSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126207.aspx)